# Openlayers 3 - get Geometry of a VectorTile to highlight features

Tags: openlayers, vector-tiles

I am trying to highlight features when mouse interaction is triggered over a VectorTile layer.

I have followed some examples but there is no one that makes what I would like to do. The most likely is [this VectorTile properties example](http://openlayersbook.github.io/ch05-using-vector-layers/example-09.html) but it only shows how to get properties. At this point, I tried different things.

First, I have seen the [OL3 hover vector layer example](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.2.1/examples/vector-layer.html?q=hover) and I tried to apply to a VectorLayer without any success.

Then, I tried to get the geometry of the feature adding it to an empty VectorLayer which every time will contain only those features under mouse position. Then I could apply a custom style to highlight these features. I added the following function:

```
    ...

    map.on('pointermove', function(e) {

      for (var i = 0; i < highlightedFeatures.length; i++) {
        highlightedFeatures[i].setStyle(null);
      }

      highlightedFeatures = [];

      map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(e.pixel, function(feature, layer) {
          if (feature.setStyle) {

            // Here I change the syle for those features that belongs 
            // to other type of layers (no VectorTiles)

            feature.setStyle(selectStyle);
            highlightedFeatures.push(feature);

          } else {
            console.log(feature.getProperties());
            console.log(feature.getType());
            // I get the polygons but they are very strange!
            console.log(feature.getGeometry());
          }
      });
    });   

    ...
```

I realised about **console.log(feature.getGeometry());** method is showing an object that seems having a strange coordinates arrays:

```
    hk {
    a : Array[4]
        0 : 16741 
        1 : 28882 
        2 : 28553 
        3 : 4217
        length : 4
        __proto__ :  Array[0]
    b : Array[64]
        0 : 20751  
        1 : 28942  
        2 : 22853 
        3 : 30064 
        4 : 20135 
        ... // a lot of "coordinates"
        length : 64
        __proto__ : Array[0]
    c : Array[1]
        closure_uid_123785828 : 23488
    f : Object
        codi : "CF7692N9826901" 
        f_id : 5849
        layer : "coverage" 
        __proto__ : Object
    g : "Polygon" 
        __proto__ : Object
    }
```

Does anyone know why the coordinates are wrong? If I add the feature I get an error. Maybe someone knows how to get Geometries of VectorTile layers in a different way.

I am using OL3 v3.17.1 and I am using srs 3857.

I guess is not important but the highlighting style referenced variables before are:

```
    var highlightedFeatures = [],
    selectStyle = new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#0d47a1',
            width: 12
        }),
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
            radius: 5.5,
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: '#0d47a1',
                width: 12
            })
        })
    });
```

Comment: You'll find it much easier to intepret the structure of OpenLayers objects if you use the debug version of the library (ol-debug.js). That said, the coordinates are determined by the 'layout' parameter to the ol.geom.Polygon constructor, in this case 'XY'. This means that the array items are alternately the X and Y coordinates. See the API docs for [ol.geom.Polygon](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.geom.Polygon.html).

Can you post the error you're getting when you add the feature to your highlight layer?

Answer (score 1):

There is an important property that you missed!

According to the [documentation](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.format.MVT.html), you can set feature class to **ol.Feature**

```
new ol.source.VectorTile({
    format: new ol.format.MVT({
        featureClass: ol.Feature
    })
});
```